# Does make_shared ignore explicit specifier?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    explicit A(int x) 
    { 
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

void Foo(A ) {}

std::shared_ptr<A> Foo2(int x)
{
    // why does this work?
    return std::make_shared<A>(x);
}

int main()
{
    A a(0);
    Foo(a);
    // Foo(1); does not compile
    Foo2(2);
}
```

I have a `class A` with an explicit marked constructor so that it doesn't convert from `int` to the `class A`  implicitly. But in a call to `std::make_shared` I can call and create this class by only passing an `int`. Why is that possible and is there something wrong in the way how I do it?

Comment: Your are explicit with `std::make_shared<A>`...

Comment: That would be a strange limitation and inconsistency. How would you then want to create a `shared_ptr` for `A` using the  `explicit A(int x)` constructor?  The only way then would be writing `shared_ptr<A>(new A(0))`. But if `shared_ptr<A>(new A(0))` is allowed why should `std::make_shared<A>(0)` not be? Because  `make_shared<A>` is meant to construct `A` based on the arguments passed to `make_shared`?

Comment: @Jarod42 That makes sense of course. I think my misunderstanding here was because I could create a pointer to A without "EXPLICITLY" calling a constructor. But of course the type is well-known because I define it in the template...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, because [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) performs [direct-intialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which considers explicit constructors too.

> The object is constructed as if by the expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.

`Foo(1);` doesn't work because the parameter gets [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which won't consider explicit constructors.